# How to run a bash script with multiple files to get single output?

Tags: bash, scripts

I Would like to run multiple file.dat files through a bash script and generate a single output out.dat file. Could anyone help me with how to do that?

Thank you.

Comment: You will need to give more details about your workflow - how exactly are .dat files run "through" the script? Are their names passed as command-line arguments? Their contents streamed via standard input? Likewise, does the script write its output to a file, or stream it via standard output?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Standard output in linux can be redirected to a file using the `>` redirection symbol. `>>` will *append* to an existing file.

Thus, if you redirect the output of processing different files to the same file using the `>>` operator, all output will end up in a single file. The syntax is

```
my_bash_script >> Output.txt
```